# Lifetimes in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

Occasionally I've found myself wanting to write functions that can be called in either of two ways:

```
// With a string literal:
let lines = read_file_lines("data.txt");

// With a string pointer:
let file_name = ~"data.txt";
let lines = read_file_lines(file_name);
```

My first guess was to use a borrowed pointer (`&str`) for the parameter type, but when that didn't work (it only allowed me to use `@str` and `~str`), I tried the following (by copying the Rust libraries), which did work.

```
fn read_file_lines<'a>(path: &'a str) -> ~[~str] {
    let read_result = file_reader(~Path(path));
    match read_result {
        Ok(file) => file.read_lines(),
        Err(e) => fail!(fmt!("Error reading file: %?", e))
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't understand what I'm doing. From what I can gather (mostly from compiler errors), I'm declaring a lifetime on which there is no restriction, and using it to describe the path parameter (meaning that any lifetime can be passed as the parameter).

So:

- Is my understanding vaguely accurate?
- What is a lifetime? Where can I learn more about them?
- What is the difference between a parameter of type `&str` and a parameter of type `&'a str` in the example above?
- And while I'm at it, what is `'self`?

(I'm using Rust 0.7, if it makes a difference to the answer)

Comment: I am not confident enough about lifetimes to answer your questions. However, I can tell you the type of `"data.txt"` is `&'static str`, which is a statically allocated string.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

*Update 2015-05-16*: the code in the original question applied to an old version of Rust, but the concepts remain the same. This answer has been updated to use modern Rust syntax/libraries. (Essentially changing `~[]` to `Vec` and `~str` to `String` and adjusting the code example at the end.)

> Is my understanding vaguely accurate?
>   [...]
>   What is the difference between a parameter of type &str and a parameter of type &'a str in the example above?

Yes, a lifetime like that says essentially "no restrictions", sort of. Lifetimes are a way to connect output values with inputs, i.e. `fn foo<'a, T>(t: &'a T) -> &'a T` says that `foo` returns a pointer that has the same lifetime as `t`, that is, the data it points to is valid for the same length of time as `t` (well, strictly, at least as long as). This basically implies that the return value points to some subsection of the memory that `t` points to.

So, a function like `fn<'a>(path: &'a str) -> Vec<String>` is very similar to writing `{ let x = 1; return 2; }`... it's an unused variable.

Rust assigns default lifetimes when writing `&str`, and this is exactly equivalent to writing the unused-variable lifetime. i.e. `fn(path: &str) -> Vec<String>` is no different to the version with `'a`s. The only time leaving off a lifetime is different to including it is if you need to enforce a global pointer (i.e. the special `'static` lifetime), or if you want to return a reference (e.g. `-> &str`) which is only possible if the return value has a lifetime (and this must be either the lifetime of one-or-more of the inputs, or `'static`).

> What is a lifetime? Where can I learn more about them?

A lifetime is how long the data a pointer points to is guaranteed to exist, e.g. a global variable is guarantee to last "forever" (so it's got the special lifetime `'static`). One neat way to look at them is: lifetimes connect data to the stack frame on which their owner is placed; once that stack frame exits, the owner goes out of scope and any pointers to/into that value/data-structure are no longer valid, and the lifetime is a way for the compiler to reason about this. (With the stack frame view, it is as if `@` has a special stack frame associated with the current task, and `static`s have a "global" stack frame).

There's also a [lifetimes chapter of the book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/lifetimes.html), and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Aatch/5734372) (NB. the code is now outdated but the concepts are still true) is a neat little demonstration of how one can use lifetimes to avoid having to copy/allocate (with a strong safety guarantee: no possibility of dangling pointers).

> And while I'm at it, what is `'self`?

Literally nothing special, just certain places require types to have lifetimes (e.g. in struct/enum defintions and in `impl`s), and currently `'self` and `'static` are the only accepted names. `'static` for global always-valid pointers, `'self` for something that can have any lifetime. It's a bug that calling that (non-`static`) lifetime anything other than `self` is an error.

---

All in all, I'd write that function like:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::path::Path;

fn read_file_lines(path: &Path) -> Vec<String> {
    match File::open(path) {
        Ok(file) => {
            let read = BufReader::new(file);
            read.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect()
        }
        Err(e) => panic!("Error reading file: {}", e)
    }
}

fn main() {
   let lines = read_file_lines(Path::new("foo/bar.txt"));
   // do things with lines
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like you're right about specifying the lifetime being redundant in my example. I think I needed it for 0.6 to use the method with `'static str`s, but didn't re-test after upgrading to 0.7.

Comment: Just read the tutorial: it (along with your explanation) was helpful. Thanks again.

I've also got a bunch of `impl<'self> MyExtraFunction for &'self str` (to do `"hello".my_extra_function()`), but it looks like I'll still need those.

Comment: @Daniel, no problem :) (yes `impl`s are one of the places where borrowed pointers are required to have lifetimes, i.e. you can't write `impl MyExtraFunction for &str` at the moment.)

Comment: (Also, [join us on IRC](http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23rust) if you haven't already; there's normally several people more than willing to help.)

Comment: There is nothing like `'self` now, right? When googling I found people suggesting to use `'self` for indicating struct instance liftime but I didn't find any sort of tacking issue or RFC. There are no plans for `'self`, right?

Comment: *that is, the data it points to is valid for the same length of time as ·t· (well, strictly, at least as long as).* Shouldn't it be *as most as long as*? As soon as `t` falls out of its scope, the return value would become invalid.

Comment: @nalzok: You're right in a sense, but this is fairly subtle. The actual value pointed to by the returned reference has to last at least as long as `t`: if the value lasted for a shorter time, the reference may become invalid before `t`, and this would be bad. However, the compiler has to assume the shortest/worse case (the return value being valid exactly as long as `t`), so you're right that when `t` goes out of scope, the compiler disallows using the return value.