# DuplexStream across tasks and closures

Tags: rust

I'm having trouble with [lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490716/lifetimes-in-rust/17493553#17493553) and borrowed points. I've read the manual and borrowed pointer tutorial, but... I'm still stuck.

Sketch of `main.rs`

```
fn main() {
  let (db_child, repo_child):(DuplexStream<~str, ~str>, DuplexStream<~str, ~str>) = DuplexStream();
    do spawn {
        slurp_repos(&repo_child);
    }
}
```

Sketch of `repos.rs`

```
fn slurp_repos(chan: &'static DuplexStream<~str, ~str>) {
    ...
    do request.begin |event| {
        ...
        chan.send(api_url);
    }
}
```

When I compile these modules, main.rs has the following error:

```
main.rs:21:20: 21:31 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
main.rs:21         slurp_repos(&repo_child);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
note: borrowed pointer must be valid for the static lifetime...
main.rs:13:10: 1:0 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 13:10
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I can't quite figure out how to declare my DuplexStreams lifetime static. Or perhaps this was the wrong way to go in the function type for slurp_repos.

If you want to see the full context:

- [main.rs](https://github.com/ozten/learning_rust/blob/b8e9d5bad6fbc3ad8fd9150c8fa739a9aaae5530/main.rs#L13-L21)
- [repos.rs](https://github.com/ozten/learning_rust/blob/b8e9d5bad6fbc3ad8fd9150c8fa739a9aaae5530/repository_metadata_slurp.rs#L93-L126)

Comment: Shouldn't you define repo_child as managed (`@`)?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to declare @repo_child. Do you have an example that compiles?

Comment: I guess one way of solving this is to have a state object which you update in the closure and then use the channel after you come back from `request.begin`. [This seems to work](https://github.com/ozten/learning_rust/commit/c002cc6881dd8bf3d39f653e6f52a7adcb987181).

Comment: Cool you made it work. so it's solved?

Comment: I haven't kept up to date with the latest changes to Rust's lifetime system, but I think only basically constant things can be static. Since you create the DuplexStream in main, I would think this couldn't be static. I might be wrong though.

Comment: have to tried to remove the 'static?

Comment: @MaikKlein He indeed did, check the diff in the third comment.

Comment: try `let a= repo_child; slurp_repos(&a);` and remove the 'static and use `fn <'a> slerp_repos(&'a ...)`;

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to test, but I guess the solution is to move the `repo_child` stream into `slurp_repos`, that is:

```
fn main() {
  let (db_child, repo_child) = DuplexStream();
    do spawn {
        slurp_repos(repo_child);
    }
}

fn slurp_repos(chan: DuplexStream<~str, ~str>) {
    ...
    do request.begin |event| {
        ...
        chan.send(api_url);
    }
}
```

By moving the whole endpoint, it allows it to be transferred across tasks (because a `DuplexStream` is `Send`able). Also, note that sharing (what the use of a references allows) the endpoint of a basic bidirectional stream (which is what `DuplexStream` is) doesn't really make sense: there can only be one person at each end of a telephone.

The error message about `repo_child` not living long enough is because the type of `slurp_repos` requires something that is `'static` i.e. lasts for the whole lifetime of the program, but `repo_child` definitely doesn't: it is local to a function.

The reason the compiler tells you to put `'static` on `slurp_repos`, is because the only `Send`able reference is one with this lifetime. This restriction is required because you could have the owning task finish before the borrowing task does, and then destroy/deallocate the reference, leaving a dangling pointer; in diagrams:

```
start program/call main
  |
  v
allocate repo_child
  |
  v
spawn -----------------> slurp_repos(chan = &repo_child)
  |                          |
  v                          v
finish                   do things with the chan reference to repo_child
  |                          |
  v                          v
deallocate repo_child    general work ...
                             |
                             v
                         do more things with chan: 
                           oops, already freed; use-after-free bug
```