# What does + 'a lifetime syntax do in rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
Self: Sized + 'a
```

or

```
T: T + 'a
```

Seen this syntax while following a tutorial which suggests using rust 2018 edition instead of 2021 if it is related to your answer. However, I can not find the meaning of `+ lifetime parameter` syntax.

Comment: Does this similar question help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048673/

Comment: No, I know about lifetimes, just the + syntax is not mentioned anywhere I looked. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that whatever type you use in the generic must outlive `'a`, which means that all references it contains must outlive `'a`. Here's some types that will always work.

```rs
i32                 // contains no lifetimes, so all zero lifetimes outlive 'a
Vec<u8>             // same as above
&'static str        // 'static outlives all lifetimes
SomeStruct<'static> // same as above
```

Here's some types that will only work if their lifetimes outlive `'a`.

```rs
Vec<&'b u8>               // 'b must outlive 'a
&'c str                   // 'c must outlive 'a
SomeStruct<'d>            // 'd must outlive 'a
AnotherStruct<'x, 'y, 'z> // all lifetimes must outlive 'a
```

This is most often used with `+ 'static`, which means "all contained lifetimes must be `'static`". You may also see it on trait objects like `Box<dyn Error + 'a>` and `impl Trait` types like `impl Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a`, where it means "this type only lives for `'a`", just like a regular lifetime parameter.

I don't think anything about this has changed since the 2018 edition.

Comment: Do you also have an official explanation. Thank you for this one.

Comment: @yokus https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html

Comment: It's worth adding that the name `'a` for the lifetime is arbitrary. Often lifetime specifiers are named in alphabetical order, but that's just a questionable convention. You can also give them more descriptive names such as `'serialization` or `'inner_borrow` depending on the lifetime they describe. In the given example, `'b` must not outlive `'a`, because `b` comes after `a` in the alphabet, but because of the lifetime constraints introduced by the program structure.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer with reference. Really appreciate it! :)