# What is 'a used for in Rust signatures?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I see signatures like:

```
fn get<'a>(&'a self, index: uint) -> &'a T
```

For a impl<T> Vec<T>, but I cannot find a clear explanation of the `'a` part in the tutorial, the guide or the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `'a` is a lifetime, representing that the returned `&T` reference is valid for (at least) as long as the `self` reference. This occurs when the returned reference points to memory owned by one of the input parameters (or points into a reference stored in the input parameters), with the named lifetime informing the compiler of the exact relationship by linking the references that have an "ownership connection".

Further information:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493553/1256624) (it's old now, so the code won't compile, but the explanations still hold)
- [The "References and Lifetimes guide"](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/guide-lifetimes.html) (in particular the "named lifetime" section at the end)

Comment: Just a note. The links in answer is broken and here's current (0.13 nightly) version of guide document: http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-ownership.html