# How do lifetimes in Rust work for a function?

Tags: rust, lifetime

In the definition of `lifetime_things`, the lifetime of `'b` is longer than `'a`, but actually when I call this function, `x1` is longer than `y1`, but this can compile successfully:

```
//here you could see 'b:'a means, the lifetime of b should be larger than a,
fn lifetime_things<'a,'b:'a>(x:&'a String, y:&'b String) ->&'a String {
  if x.len() > y.len() {
    &x
  } else {
    &y
  }
}

fn main() {
let z: i32;
    let x = String::from("1");
    let x1=&x;
    {
        let y = String::from("2");
        let y1=&y;
        println!("{}",lifetime_things(x1,y1));
    }
}
```

But here you could see the lifetime of `x1` should be larger than `y1` so why can this compile successfully as well?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Is there one ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lifetimes in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490716/lifetimes-in-rust)

Comment: `'a` is *not* the lifetime of `x1`, but rather *some lifetime* (that is no longer than `x1`).  Likewise `'b`.

Answer (score 4):

`'b: 'a` means `'b` must outlive `'a`, which in turn means whenever `'a` is live, so must `'b`. Crucially, this is a larger than **or equals** relationship. Also notice that lifetimes don't work like types. When a function takes an `'v` reference, any lifetime (`'w`) will be accepted as long as `'w: 'v`.

So, where is `'a` live? In the body of the function and whenever the returned string reference is used after the call. We can visualize it like this:

```rust
fn lifetime_things<'a,'b:'a>(x:&'a String, y:&'b String) ->&'a String {
  if x.len() > y.len() {                         // <-+
    &x                                           //   |
  } else {                                       //   |
    &y                                           //   +----+
  }                                              //   |    |
}                                                // <-+    |
                                                 //        |
fn main() {                                      //        +-- 'a
let z: i32;                                      //        |
    let x = String::from("1");                   //        |
    let x1=&x;                                   //        |
    {                                            //        |
        let y = String::from("2");               //        |
        let y1=&y;                               //        |
        println!("{}",lifetime_things(x1,y1));   // <------+
    }
}
```

Notice, that since the value returned by `lifetime_things` is only printed, `'a` is only live on the line `println!("{}",lifetime_things(x1,y1));` (exclusing `lifetime_things`s body).

So, to call `lifetime_things` we simply need the both arguments to **at least** be live at the call. This holds for both `x1` and `y1`, so it all checks out.